# Server 2012 replication error

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain, replication

I have 2 Windows 2012 DCs (DC1 and DC2).

From DC2 replication works while from DC1 I keep getting the error "replication error rpc server is unavailable. I'm attempting to do this from Active Directory Sites and Services.

DNS functions correctly and am able to ping with both hostname and IP. All was functioning correctly until when yesterday we switched on an old DC3 which has not been utilized for a year or 2. DC3 has been powered off.

Any suggestions on how I could solve the replication issue between DC1 and 2 please?

Comment: `All was functioning correctly until when yesterday we switched on an old DC3 which has not been utilized for a year or 2` - Oh man, that wasn't a good thing to do. Download and run this tool - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30005

Comment: It was indeed. When running repadmin /showrepl, the failed replication now suceeds however keeps failing from active directory sites and services.

Comment: @joebegborg07: My psychic powers tell me you haven't deleted DC3 yet from AD Sites and Services?

Comment: @GregAskew Your psychic powers are right haha. I'll be removing it. Should that fix the issue ?